# How do I answer? My question was about the wrong problem in my code

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

I was mistaken in what was the error [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747146/error-instantiating-an-inner-class-in-parents-constructor) (and thus, the title of the question has nothing to do with the actual issue). Turned out the issue had nothing to do with inner class instantiation. It was an issue with calling a method of the parent class in the parent class's constructor ... which isn't even included in my psuedo-code.

What's the best way to 'answer' this question, since the title is misleading to the issue, and once I discovered it, a simple comment in my question said "oh, this question wasn't actually my problem..."

Do I delete the question? Change the title? Answer it myself and explain?

It just seems to be misleading and less than helpful when the title has nothing to do with the actual issue.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a reference for other people searching the solution for the same problem. If your title is incorrect, change it! Explain in the body of your questions, that you made a mistake and changed the stuff.

Also leave a comment to the answerers, telling them, that your missed the real problem and their answers are not valid any more. They won't like it, but life is a bitch. It's no help for other people reading misguided answers (misguided = question pointed in the wrong direction).

Self-answer only, if you have a solution to your problem.

Comment: I second that, but please don't kill any more ladybugs.

Answer (score 3):

Edit your question, stating that it isn't the right question, flag it for moderator attention so it can be closed. Create a new question and then answer your own question with the correct question content.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I would consider several options, or combination of them:

1. Add an edit in the question explaining what the question should have been - i.e. where your question was incorrect.
2. Write a new question as it should be and then answer it.
3. If any of the answers fit the question as you originally wrote it, give the best answer it's due and at the very least accept it. If you do select an answer, provide a comment that the chosen answer is the best fit based on the way you wrote the question.
4. Edit the title to correctly reflect the question you *did* ask so future searches will find this question.

Comment: How does he know, that one of the answers solves the original problem? He has never had the problem. So he can only guess. I wouldn't do that.

Comment: @Ladybug: That's why I mentioned them as *options*.